# Codeigniter 4 is_unique rule validation throws not unique error when I update record

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-query-builder

I have a simple form that stores some data in the database and for the **Title** field I have an **is_unique** validation rule along with others. Following are my validation rules from the **TaskModel**:

```
protected $validationRules = [
        'Title' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]|is_unique[tasks.Title]',
        'Description' => 'required|max_length[300]',
        'CreatedAt' => 'required',
        'UpdatedAt' => 'required',
        'DueDate' => 'required|ValidateDueDate[DueDate]',
        'AssignedTo' => 'required',
        'Author' => 'required'
    ];
```

Now everything is working as intended when adding data to the Database. **The Problem is when I try to update a record let's say I change the author name and when I submit the form it says the title should be unique. I want it to ignore the record row from the database I am editing and check input's uniqueness with others.** Can you help me achieve this? I am thinking of passing the record id with the form and ignoring it when checking uniqueness but I don't know how to pass the Id to the validation rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the Id of row as parameter in the **is_unique** rule. Like

```
is_unique[tasks.Title,Id,{Id}]
```

Hope this helps :)

**UPDATE: More Detailed Explanation**

Second parameter **Id** is database field name. Third one is the **Id** that is passed from the form. For this purpose add a hidden field in the edit form then set its `name = Id` and  its `value=$data['Id']`. Where `$data['Id']` is the **Id** of the row fetched from the Database and passed to the view. So when the form will be submitted and **Id** will be submitted in `$_POST`. Which is then passed to rule parameter as:
`{Id}`

**HOPE THIS HELPS :(**

Comment: Can you please elaborate more this third parameter 'Id' is which Id ?